# Memory management for a tree object implementation in js

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, quadtree

I try to implement a *quad tree* and I have a question about the clear function.
For the moment, the tree is re-build at each step update and before that, we must clear the current structure.

I saw some differents implementations like [this](https://github.com/mikechambers/ExamplesByMesh/blob/master/JavaScript/QuadTree/src/QuadTree.js).
In the clear method, we nullify the objects array and the sub-nodes array 
**recursively** `(array.length = 0)`.

Why? Is the behavior of the garbage collector is different if we simply nullify the root node? ('cause the sub-nodes can't be accessible anymore) **or its a 'just to be sure' issue ?**

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like "just to be sure" to me.

Comment: Ok ! I'll update soon the topic after tests. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript objects are passed by "copy of a reference".

So even if you nullify the root node, yes, sub-nodes are not accessible anymore in easy way, but propably somewhere there are existing references to it so they stay in memory.

Simple example:

```
var o = {
    c: {
        a: true
    }
};

var reference_to_c = o.c;
o = null; // just removes reference

console.log(reference_to_c); // Object {a: true}
```

## EDIT:

About `array.length = 0;`: David Walsh  explains [here](http://davidwalsh.name/empty-array), why using this way of removing elements does not involve memory issues and empty pointers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I saw that JavaScript objects (and primitives) are garbage collected when they become inaccessible.
So, in your exemple, c is not collected because of reference_to_c and if we set reference_to_c = null, it will be collected. It's right ?

Comment: Yes, I think that garbage collection works this way. I updated an answer, so maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for you help ! Therefore if we follow that logic, what is the interest of a recursively clear (the children in my example, have not ref to their parent) ?

Comment: I think that is more to remove ref from parent to children and siblings and to ensure that garbage collector will collect everything they are doing it recursively for every node. Propably it is "just to be sure" issue.

Comment: I suppose too and that's the reason of my question (avoid a recursion for gain cpu time). I updated it. Thanks Mateusz !

Comment: "*… are not accessible anymore, but they stay in memory*" - well, no. If they cannot be reached any more, they will be garbage-collected.

Comment: Those JS Coding Guidelines are totally wrong. A shame to find such things in an Apple document (albeit an old one). Please read [Understanding `delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/), do *not* follow this advice, and immediately remove it from your answer.

Comment: @Bergi - I have just noticed "Retired document" note at the footer of pdf. My fault! About staying in memory - I meant that if we have somewhere reference to a variable it wont be collected. I tried to show it in example. Answer edited.